# How does it know the address of the DB without passing it to the Schemas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nuxt.js

It is not usual to ask a question when something is working, but this is working to well. 
I am using a connection with a Mongodb in a Nuxt application.

The only place the address of the DB is declared is in the **index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const apiRouter = require('./apiRouter');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/sun-v2', {useNewUrlParser: true})

app.use(apiRouter);

module.exports = {
   path: '/server',
   handler: app
}
```

As you can see the mongoose Object is not exported.
In my **apiRouter.js** the Models are required and works perfectly:

```
const express = require('express');
const PlayerModel = require('./models/player');
const app = express();

app.get('/players', async (req, res) => {
    const players = await PlayerModel.find({});

    try {
        res.send(players);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }
});
```

What I don't understand is how the `Model.find()` knows where to search for the DB, if neither the path nor the connection is exported.

What if I had more than one DB address, how could I choose the connection I want to use?
I have more than one open mongo database, how does it know it has to use the one I made connection to in index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `mongoose.connect()`, mongoose is creating a connection internally and making it the "default connection". This is a convenience that works for most of the cases.

If you need more than one connection then you have to create them manually by using the method `mongoose.createConnection()` (which is the method used by `mongoose.connect()` under the hood).

```js
const conn = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost/sun-v2", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
```

There is one caveat though, you cannot simply export you **models** anymore. You will have to export you **schemas** instead, so you can create separate models for each connection. In your case you will have something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Export your schema instead your model
const PlayerSchema = require('./models/player');
const app = express();

const conn1 = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost/sun-v2", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
const conn2 = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://anotherhost/sun-v2", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});


// ...

const PlayerModel1 = conn1.model('User', PlayerSchema);
const PlayerModel2 = conn2.model('User', PlayerSchema);

// ...

app.get('/players', async (req, res) => {
    const playersFromConn1 = await PlayerModel1.find({});
    const playersFromConn2 = await PlayerModel2.find({});

    // ...
});
```

You can check the Mongoose documentation for more information about multiple connections on https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections